# Java servlet is returning a 404 error

Tags: java, exception, servlets

I have a java servlet that was working as of last night.  However, it is now returning a HTTP Status 404 whenever I call it.  It worked the last night before shutting down.

Nothing has changed since yesterday when it last worked.

The servlet is mapped in the web.xml file.

Curiously, non of the servlets can be seen anymore - all return 404 error.

I am using Eclipse and running on the localhost.

Ideas?

**EDIT**

Okay, now it's working - !?  Not sure what I did, everything is now working.

Comment: Application isn't deployed due to some reason, check Tomcat (or your Servlet container) logs.

Comment: is your app deployed successfully ?

Comment: The jsp files load okay, but I will check the Tomcat logs.

Comment: Does not appear to be anything in the logs other than the respective error 192.168.0.14 - - [30/Nov/2012:17:33:39 -0600] "POST /appDomain/api/init HTTP/1.1" 404 1045

Comment: We need more information for Diagnoses: Check your Server Log files and Post any relevant data

Comment: I verified that the application is getting deployed and all classes are in their respective folders (namespaces).

Comment: Not likely, but could a Windows 7 update (which did happen at shutdown last night) potentially be involved?

Comment: 404 errors are not 'thrown'. They are returned as part of a response.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but where might I find the Servlet container logs?  I have found the access logs in the folder in the org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1 folder.  This is where it is deployed locally under the wtpwebapps folder.

Comment: Search for catalina.out if you are using Tomcat.

Comment: Cannot find anything of consequence searching for catalina.out.  found a couple of directories in the tomcat documentation.  That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application not deployed completly for some reson. Its server error...first clear your project then Redeploy your project... Still not working then post your server name and web.xml

Comment: I cleaned the project several times w/o it fixing the problem.  What would cause the application not to fully deploy?

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you and all others that the project did not deploy properly.  For this reason, I will accept your answer.  But, I would really like to better understand why it did not deploy properly.